c++ typewriter effect delay issues?
I have created this code to create a typewriter console effect:
void fastType(const std::string& text, int delay)
{
    for (char c : text)
    {
        std::cout << c;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(delay));
    }
}

void fastType(const std::string& text, int delay = 2);

Example usage:
std::string message = "hello world...";

fastType(message);

In Debug mode, the function seems to have a delay faster than 10 milliseconds, but when I set it to Release mode, it seems to have a delay of around 10 milliseconds and not printing any faster? I have absolutely no clue as to why this could be happening. Also, I am using Visual Studio 2022.
I tried changing it to std::chrono::milliseconds(delay) and set the delay lower than 10 milliseconds and it didn't become any faster. I tried adding std::cout.flush(); before the line: std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(delay)); and it did not do anything (chatgpt said to try that). I am genuinely stumped and have no idea what is causing this issue so any tips on how I could print paragraphs of text quickly with a typewriter effect would be greatly appreciated!
NOTE: I am NOT actually trying to set the delay to 2 nanoseconds but rather experimenting with how to make the delay shorter than 16ms and why this is happening.

From using VS 2022 I infer you are on Windows. It has some limitations for sleep minimum duration and thread scheduling (the minimum effective sleep interval used to be ~16 milliseconds, that could have changed but the principle remains).

sleeping at (or lower than) the microsecond scale makes very little sense. especially if humans are supposed to perceive the delay.

@wohlstad, that must mean that on release mode this 16 millisecond limitation is only prominent then, maybe due to optimisation? is there any possible work around this other than setting it to debug mode?

@Eljay, I tried adding std::cout.flush(); on the line before std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(delay)); and it did not work.

@Botje, this function is intended for paragraph texts and hence the delay is able to be perceived.

I very much doubt that you could spot a delay of two nanoseconds. It takes far more than two nanoseconds to just output a character without a delay.

@Zrylx Windows has a mechanism called Multimedia Timers. They offer better and more precise timers than the default ones. But to be honest just for getting a typewritter-like effect it seems a huge overkill. You shoud simply increase the sleep duration - having such a short duration doesn't really make sense because of the perception limitations of us humans (as mentioned above).

@wohlstad, thank you for that, I will probably just print out the paragraphs with no typewriter effect. Also, it seems to me that Debug mode has some kind of lower limit below 16 millisecond that is slower than 2 nanoseconds and thus I was seeing the text outputted faster than 16 milliseconds. I set it to 2 nanoseconds for testing purposes and it outputted faster so I kept it like that. Thanks for everyone’s answers however, very helpful!

I think you are grossly over-estimating how short 2 ns is. Given a screen of characters (say about 2000 chars) this would take 4 microseconds to display it all. Think about a "blink of a human eye" is approx 250milliseconds. At 4microseconds per screen you could display a WHOLE screen of text 62 thousand times in the blink of a human eye at 2ns per char. This is probably about a thousand times faster than the physical display refresh rate of your monitor.

Corollary: If "2ns works in debug mode" is true, it is definitively not because its actually pausing for 2ns.

@MikeVine, lol yes it would be quite fast. I set it to 2 nanoseconds for testing purposes (may of been a little to fast) and it outputted faster so I kept it like that and by the looks of it debug mode has a lower limit than 16 milliseconds.

try calling timeBeginPeriod(1) before you run your code. That'll lower the windows scheduling quantum. However, unless this is a toy project this is definitely not a good idea as it uses a lot of battery this way. A better way would be to pause for say 50ms and then write out enough characters that it looks good - say the next 100 - and then pause for another 50ms, etc.

@MikeVine, thank you for that, I will probably just print out the paragraphs with no typewriter effect. I was mainly trying to make the characters print out a bit faster than 16 ms and it seems that doing so in any type of way will use too much power.

The 16ms floor is imposed by windows OS. It's not a simple std library issue. If debug mode seems to be doing that, it's probably a bug.

@Red.Wave, interesting, I guess i just accidentally managed to bypass windows OS limitations then.. or maybe my debug mode can bend time :)

Please provide [mcve]. This works for me perfectly.

@MarekR OP is using Visual Studio. And they have a problem when timing is set to less than 10ms (although I honestly can't tell how 2ns delay would be perceivable to anyone)

@Yksisarvinen I do not get what impact VS has on his problem. Just test my code on my Windows machine with MSVC 19.41.34120 with same positive results. Fact that he used absurd short delay time, may be a source of problems.

OP, 2ns is about ten instructions out of L1 cache, no system call in the world could conceivably run that fast. Humans have real trouble noticing anything below about the Windows default interval of 16ms, it's not wrong of it to use that granularity. Using your 2ns delay a 1000-character paragraph would incur a total 2μs delay, utterly imperceptible. Work out how many characters you can display in a 60hz refresh frame, display that many, then sleep for 16ms, repeat.

Every body here is telling you that you have a missreading on the debug behavior of your program. Nothing magical has happened. Something is wrong and almost certainly some part of your code is broken. It's a famous meme: it works, but I don't know how. Nothing to chill or be happy about.

I’m sorry, but like I have said multiple times, I have REMOVED this code for its original intended use (paragraphs) and instead am printing the paragraphs normally. I understand that 2ns is an absurdly short amount of time but since the text printed faster I left it there (it obviously did NOT print at 2ns but it did print faster than 16ms).

I posted this question with the main intent to understand WHY this happens and how to make it shorter than 16ms (not to set its delay to actually 2ns) and from what everyone is saying, it’s just because I set it to such a short amount of time and that caused windows OS to bug out.

im sum, I am NOT actually trying to set the delay to 2ns.

This issue actually involves the thread scheduling of the operating system and some of the underlying principles of the code.
Because the Microsoft documentation related to the std::this_thread::sleep_for() function does not explain its underlying implementation， I will use the Sleep() method here:
void Sleep(
 [in] DWORD dwMilliseconds
);

This method has a more detailed explanation in the documentation， so we can figure it out why delaytime not cant be less than 16ms.
The operating system has a timer used for scheduling tasks, which often has a resolution typically between 10 to 15 milliseconds. And this is the system clock resolution.
The operating system schedules system threads based on this clock cycle. If your thread's sleep time is too short, such as 0.01 ms, then, as mentioned in the documentation, the actual sleep time will be less than the set time. However, if the sleep time is around 3 ms or 5 ms, which is within the same precision but less than the system clock cycle, the thread will wait until the next clock cycle to be executed. That's why the delay time not always like your expect.
In the official documentation, to address this situation, the methods timeBeginPeriod(5);, timeBeginPeriod(), and timeEndPeriod() are provided to adjust the precision of the system clock. The variables in these two methods must be consistent and used immediately before and after the timer.
I also wrote a piece of code regarding testing thread delays for your reference. It can set a delay of less than 16 ms in both release and debug modes. Of course, you can also use your original method, which has been tested and is also effective.  The reason for using the Sleep() method here is that its underlying logic can be found in the official documentation. In contrast, the documentation for std::this_thread::sleep_for() does not provide a detailed explanation of its logic, so we can only infer that its logic is similar to that of Sleep().
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
 
#include <timeapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
int main()
{
 
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
 
std::cout << "Hello waiter\n" << std::flush;
 
const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 
timeBeginPeriod(10);
//std::this_thread::sleep_for(6ms) ;   // sleep_for() works too.
Sleep(6);
timeEndPeriod(10);
const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end - start;
 
std::cout << "Waited " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";
}

If you use it, just include the following part:
timeBeginPeriod(10);
//std::this_thread::sleep_for(6ms) ;   // sleep_for() works too.
Sleep(6);
timeEndPeriod(10);

The rest is used to monitor the sleep time.
I hope my answer can be helpful to you.

Thanks to Zhenning Zhang's answer this is how I have modified my function:
Main.cpp:
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib") //link the winmm library for multimedia functions

void fastType(const std::string& text, int delay)
{
    for (char c : text)
    {
        std::cout << c; //output the character
        Sleep(delay); //pause for delay in milliseconds
    }
}


int main()
{
    timeBeginPeriod(1); //set the timer resolution to 1 ms

    //call fast type function
    std::string paragraph = "This is a paragraph of text that should be outputted with a typewriter effect with a 2ms delay.";
    fastType(paragraph, 2); //delay of 2 milliseconds

    system("pause");

    timeEndPeriod(1); //restore the timer resolution to the default value
}

The above works perfectly for my intended use.

From the Microsoft documentation on Sleep(): "Use caution when calling timeBeginPeriod, as frequent calls can significantly affect the system clock, system power usage, and the scheduler. If you call timeBeginPeriod, call it one time early in the application and be sure to call the timeEndPeriod function at the very end of the application." (Emphasis by me.) If fastType() is called often, the timeBeginPeriod() call should perhaps be made by the caller (e.g., `main()``).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica, I have modified the answer to address this and to be more clear.
